# Remove row from datatable if column is not numeric

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, row

I have a datatable with a few columns. The first column is our employee id. Unfortunately not all of the rows are numeric and we want to remove those who aren't numeric. For instance, we have 1 row which has "@#$" and I want to remove rows like these. I currently have the following code.

```
        var len = dt.Rows.Count;
        for(int y = 0; y < len; y++)
        {
            var mwd = dt.Columns[0].ToString();
            bool valid = int.TryParse(mwd, out int n);
            if (valid)
            {
                log.LogInformation("mwd is numeric");
            }
            else
            {
                log.LogInformation("mwd is not numeric");
                dt.Rows[y].Delete();
            }
        }
```

However, this doesn't remove the row. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Surrounding code

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string[] columns = { "Mwd", "Naam", "Kostenplaats Externe id (Klant)", "Kostenplaats Loonlijstcode (Activiteit)", "Kostenplaats Naam (Activiteit)", "Datum", "Uren ruw", "Ber. Uren", "Verlof volledig pad" };
        foreach (string column in columns)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(column);
        }
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.Body))
        {
            while (reader.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                string[] rows = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
                {
                    var temp = rows[i].Trim('"');
                    dr[i] = temp.Trim('\'');
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                var mwd = dt.Rows[i][column].ToString();
                int n;
                bool valid = int.TryParse(mwd, out n);
                if (valid)
                {
                    log.LogInformation("mwd is numeric");
                }
                else
                {
                    log.LogInformation("mwd is not numeric");
                    dt.Rows[i].Delete();
                    i--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        dt.AcceptChanges();

        log.LogInformation(dt.ToString());


        for (int x = 0; dt.Rows.Count > x; x++)
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.kronos (Mwd, Naam, KostenplaatsExterneIdKlant, KostenplaatsLoonlijstcodeActiviteit, KostenplaatsNaamActiviteit, Datum, UrenRuw, BerUren, VerlofVolledigPad)" +
                " VALUES ('" + dt.Rows[x]["Mwd"].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[x]["Naam"].ToString() + "', '"
                + dt.Rows[x]["Kostenplaats Externe id (Klant)"].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[x]["Kostenplaats Loonlijstcode (Activiteit)"].ToString() + "', '"
                + dt.Rows[x]["Kostenplaats Naam (Activiteit)"].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[x]["Datum"].ToString() + "', '"
                + dt.Rows[x]["Uren ruw"].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[x]["Ber. Uren"].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[x]["Verlof volledig pad"].ToString() + "')";

            var str = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString");

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(str))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        return result;
```

Comment: Delete just marks the row as deleted inside the Datatable. This has no effect on the database. The row remains in the Datatable. If you want to remove the rows marked for deletion from the Datatable you need to call AcceptChanges at loop exit. Removing from the database requires a call to an adapter update method or single call through a dbCommand

Comment: That makes sense, But it still doesn't remove it. It still gives me the error: ```Can't convert "@#$" to int```

Comment: On which line? Int.TryParse should not give exceptions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
for (int i = 0; i< dt.Rows.Count;i++)
{
   foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
   {
       var mwd = dt.Rows[i][column].ToString();
       int n;
       bool valid = int.TryParse(mwd, out n);
       if (valid)
       {
          log.LogInformation("mwd is numeric");
       }
       else
       {
         log.LogInformation("mwd is not numeric");
         dt.Rows[i].Delete();
         i--;
         break;
       }
    }
 }
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

If you know the name of the column or its index, use the following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var mwd = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
    //or---------------------------------
    var mwd = dt.Rows[i][index].ToString();
    int n;
    bool valid = int.TryParse(mwd, out n);
    if (valid)
    {
       log.LogInformation("mwd is numeric");
    }
    else
    {
       log.LogInformation("mwd is not numeric");
       dt.Rows[i].Delete();
       i--;
    }
}
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: This works for the first row. Which in this case has the wrong value so it is correct. But when it enters the loop again it says: ```This row has been removed from a table and does not have any data. BeginEdit() will allow creation of new data in this row.```

Comment: Use break. Now I have modified the code. Copy and test the code again

Comment: What is the purpose to loop over the columns when the only column that should be tested is the one at index 0?

Comment: oke oke sorry for this but now i get the error: ```Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute```

Comment: Sorry . I modified the code. Works . I tested it. I had not tested the previous ones.

Comment: As said in my previous comment, your original code should work, unless you have some other code that surrounds the code posted. Please clarify your original question and do net us guess where your changes create new errors

Comment: @Steve Use this command if you know the column index var mwd = dt.Rows [i][index] .ToString (); and And remove the column loop

Comment: @Steve. I just edited my post with the surrounding code. Right now it doesn't give any errors but i think it deletes the entire datatable.

Comment: I added the state that you know the name of the column or its index to the post.

Comment: Guys i fixed it. Take a look at my own answer